# What species is the spider in the title sequence of Penny Dreadful?

Tags: penny-dreadful

In the title sequence of *Penny Dreadful*, we see closeups of a spider, with yellow dots on its body.

What is the exact species of this spider? Does it bear any significance, or is it just a generic creepy scene, without any relation to the plot?
*(Of course there are hunters and prey in the series, but I mean beyond that).*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're referring to the spider which appears several times throughout the intro - and not the [tarantula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarantula), which only appears once - it appears to be a species of [**Golden Orb Weaver**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_silk_orb-weaver), sometimes called a Giant Wood Spider.

[image]

This genus of spiders is very common throughout the world, typically found in warmer climates - the Southern US, Asia, Africa, and Australia. They are mostly harmless, with a moderate bite and non-aggressive temperament. They are known, however, for their creepy appearance and extravagant webs. They can also grow quite large, with a body of over 2 inches (excluding legs).

[image]

The spider does not appear to have any direct connection to the content of [the show](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penny_Dreadful_(TV_series)), and is most likely used in the intro to establish atmosphere.